# Why does OneNote API pages request return empty page list?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Few days ago our applications (iOS, Android and Windows) stopped getting the list of Pages from Microsoft OneNote via OneNote API request https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages. Request returns HTTP OK and empty content.
Source code Windows UWP appliaction C#-XAML (from Microsoft OneNote API example https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteAPISampleWinUniversal)

```
    public static string GET_PAGES_REQEST = APIENDPOINT + "sections/{0}/pages";
    public const string APIENDPOINT = "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/";
    public const string AUTHMETHOD = "Bearer";
    public const string APPJSON = "application/json";

    /// <summary>
    /// Get meta data for ALL pages under a given section
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sectionId">Id of the section for which the page are returned</param>
    /// <param name="token">Authentication token</param>
    /// <param name="isEncryptedOnly">View encrypted only notes</param>
    /// <remarks>  The sectionId can be fetched by querying the user's sections (e.g. GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections ).
    /// NOTE: Using this approach, you can still query pages with ALL the different params shown in examples above.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>The converted HTTP response message</returns>
    public static async Task<List<PageApiResponse>> GetListAsync(string sectionId, string token, bool isEncryptedOnly)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Note: API only supports JSON response.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Common.APPJSON));
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("FavorDataRecency", "true");

        // Not adding the Authentication header would produce an unauthorized call and the API will return a 401
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue
        (
            Common.AUTHMETHOD, token
        );

        // Prepare an HTTP GET request to the Pages endpoint
         var getMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        (
            HttpMethod.Get,
            isEncryptedOnly ?
                String.Format(Common.GET_PAGES_ENCRYPTED_REQEST, sectionId) :
                String.Format(Common.GET_PAGES_REQEST, sectionId)
        );

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(getMessage);

        string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new Exception(Errors.TranslateError(response));

        var content = JObject.Parse(body);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PageApiResponse>>(content["value"].ToString());

    }
```

sectionId and token is correct. isEncryptedOnly = false;

Notebooks and Sections work fine. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Hi, I am running into this same issue and was wondered if you had figured out a solution!

Comment: This issue only with my Microsoft account. I change account and now all work fine